# Cannot install SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, vps, windows-server-2012

I have a VPS and I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 (64bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard (64bit and all updates completed) with daemon tools lite (64bit) by Remote Desktop.

I can load the `.iso` file and see the setup files but when I clicked the `setup.exe` a small console screen flicks and then nothing happens.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I do not know how and why but sqlserver setup  files are corrupted.I downloaded another sqlserver setup and worked.